# Lucene.net index phrases

Tags: lucene.net

I am using Lucene.net for the search feature of a web application.
I want to search locations which constitute more than one word for an exact match(phrase based) and exclude the other match results(word based) and vice versa.
what approach should I use?
Is it possible to index phrases in Lucene.net?

Answer (score 1):

yes, use PhraseQueries

http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_4/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.html

if you use the QueryParser, phrases are specified with quotes, ie: "this is a phrase"

http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_0/queryparsersyntax.html